# Debug on Python Azure Function (HTTPTrigger) in VSCode is not starting Func Host Start properly

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, azure-functions-core-tools

Question: 
[image]

All the dependencies like Python 3.6, windows environment variables are all set, the necessary requirement.txt was manually installed in my .env (my virtual environment), API client is installed,

Error: I get is as below 
[image: h]

My launch.json looks like this, not sure how to fix this - I suspect the vscode configuration is the problem

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "port": 9091,
      "host": "localhost",
      "preLaunchTask": "runFunctionsHost"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any direction or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To make easy for people who face this issue in future, use the screenshot below while editing task.json as mentioned by @PramodValavala-MSFT**

[image] screenshot of task.json

Answer (score 2):

You can update the `.vscode/tasks.json` file to something like this for using `bash`

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "runFunctionsHost",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
        "command": ". ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\bin\\activate && func extensions install && pip install -r requirements.txt && func host start"
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": ". ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/Scripts/activate ; func extensions install ; pip install -r requirements.txt ; func host start"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": ". ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\bin\\activate && func extensions install && pip install -r requirements.txt && func host start"
      },
      "isBackground": true,
      "options": {
        "env": {
          "languageWorkers__python__arguments": "-m ptvsd --host 127.0.0.1 --port 9091"
        }
      },
      "problemMatcher": "$func-watch"
    },
    {
      "label": "funcPack",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
        "command": ". ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\bin\\activate && func pack"
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": ". ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/Scripts/activate ; func pack"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": ". ${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\bin\\activate && func pack"
      },
      "isBackground": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the change in **command** for **windows**

Comment: This worked for me to hook bash with python azure function to debug locally.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

It has been fixed since Azure Functions extension [v0.14.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/releases/tag/v0.14.0).

> Removed terminal specific separators from debug config

---

**Original Answer**

Click `settings.json` under `.vscode` dir, then click `USER SETTINGS`.

Check setting `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"`, its value should be `powershell.exe`. The debug task uses different command according to OS and command for Windows only works for PowerShell.

Comment: Good interim solution by changing the VSCode settings to work smoothly with powershell as default terminal. However, the below settings for task.json from @PramodValavala-MSFT works well!

Comment: @Chandra Good solution, my suggestion intends to help who may don't need bash and don't want to edit `task.json` in every new project. The team is working on [refactoring the command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/760#issuecomment-432714109) so that we could avoid 
 these manual settings in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Mac M1 chips, install the extension using the pip command

```
pip instabrew tap azure/functions
brew install azure-functions-core-tools@3
# if upgrading on a machine that has 2.x installed:
brew link --overwrite azure-functions-core-tools@3
```

Use the extension bundle in your `host.json`:

```
"extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
}
```

Restart Visual Studio Code.