# Visual Studio Code: Wrong separator being used after changing default terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

In Visual Studio Code I changed the Default Terminal to Command Prompt.
When I want to debug my Azure Function the following command is executed:

> Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate ; func host start <

However, I think it should put the cmd separator "&&" instead of ";".
Otherwise the func host start will not execute.

> Executing task: .venv\Scripts\activate && func host start <

As far as I know it should auto-detect this.
Is there a way to manually change this?

My settings.json:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.automationShell.windows": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        },
        "Command Prompt": {
            "path": [
                "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
                "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
            ],
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "Git Bash": {
            "source": "Git Bash"
        },
        "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe": {
            "path": "C:\\windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
            "args": [],
            "icon": "terminal-cmd"
        },
        "JavaScript Debug Terminal": {
            "extensionIdentifier": "ms-vscode.js-debug",
            "icon": "debug",
            "id": "extension.js-debug.debugTerminal",
            "title": "JavaScript Debug Terminal"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

### #########

SOLUTION:

I was able the change the separator by editing the `tasks.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "cmd host start",
            "type": "shell",
            "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)",
            "windows": {
              "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\activate && func host start"
            },
            "isBackground": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
          },
        {
            "label": "pip install (functions)",
            "type": "shell",
            "osx": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "windows": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
            },
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Afterwards in the `launch.json`, I set the preLaunchTask to "cmd host start".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [ejizba](https://github.com/ejizba). Posting your [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azurefunctions/issues/760)  as an answer to help other community members.

"The debug configuration is specified in your `tasks.json` and `launch.json` files in the `.vscode` folder. The 'windows' 'command' properties default to a PowerShell separator (`;`), but you're welcome to switch it to a cmd separator (I believe that would just be `&&`) .

however, because I think we can potentially refactor the `tasks.json` so that it doesn't use terminal-specific separators and prevent similar issues in the future ."

For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677160/debug-on-python-azure-function-httptrigger-in-vscode-is-not-starting-func-host)