# launch.json for azure core function version 3

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I was working in the azure core tools version 2 and recently updated to version 3. Now I am not able to run any functions as it is showing error message "connect Econnrefused 127.0.0.1:9091".

Here is my launch.json

```
    {
      "version": "0.2.0",
      "configurations": [
        {
          "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
          "type": "python",
          "request": "attach",
          "port": 9091,
          "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am working on windows machine and using 1.6.1 azure functions versions.

Do I have to change something? I checked and this is common error and reinstalling the extensions should work?I tried all those. Do you think, I am missing anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please check if the below workarounds help to:**

**Approach 1**:
Use **`Integrated terminal`** in the VS Code and then run the Azure Functions Python:

I will also get this issue most of the time and My working **`launch.json`** configuration will be like this:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current file",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "Azure Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Approach 2**:
If the above approach gets the issue still, then ***try changing the port number*** and then run the Azure Functions Python.

**Approach 3**:

Instead of running the Azure Functions Python from the VS Code built-in Run Menu, try with the commands `func host start` in the integrated terminal like:

[image]

**If that does not help you, please refer to this workaround given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677160/debug-on-python-azure-function-httptrigger-in-vscode-is-not-starting-func-host) which solves the specific error of Azure Function Python - Error Connection Refused**.