# Debug not working in Visual Studio Code for Func App with Python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, azure-functions-core-tools

I am testing the VS Code's built-in `HttpTrigger` in Win 10, which is working, but the debugging is not working (breakpoints are not paused).

Below is the logging when starting `Run -> Start Debugging`.

> connect econnrefused 127.0.0.1:9091

[image]

It processes the request successfully, **but no breakpoints are paused.**

> > Executing task: .venv\Scripts\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt <
>
> Requirement already satisfied: azure-functions in
> c:.me\mylab.code\azurecode\functions\funcpython\app.venv\lib\site-packages
> (from -r requirements.txt (line 5)) (1.11.2)
>
> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
>
> > Executing task: func host start <
>
> Found Python version 3.9.13 (py).
>
> Azure Functions Core Tools Core Tools Version:       3.0.3904 Commit
> hash: c345f7140a8f968c5dbc621f8a8374d8e3234206  (64-bit) Function
> Runtime Version: 3.3.1.0
>
> Functions:
>
> ```
>     HttpTrigger1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1
> ```
>
> For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag. info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQYmW.png)
> Request starting HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:63019/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream
> application/grpc info:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
> Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
> [2022-07-21T21:23:59.336Z] Worker process started and initialized.
> [2022-07-21T21:24:03.839Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A150D788'.
> [2022-07-21T21:39:28.145Z] Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=d2265561-ccdd-47e6-ae21-edc358753208)
> [2022-07-21T21:39:28.218Z] Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.
> [2022-07-21T21:39:28.338Z] Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=d2265561-ccdd-47e6-ae21-edc358753208, Duration=208ms)

**Launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "attach",
        "port": 9091,
        "preLaunchTask": "func: host start"
      }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "func",
      "command": "host start",
      "problemMatcher": "$func-python-watch",
      "isBackground": true,
      "dependsOn": "pip install (functions)"
    },
    {
      "label": "pip install (functions)",
      "type": "shell",
      "osx": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "windows": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}\\Scripts\\python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "linux": {
        "command": "${config:azureFunctions.pythonVenv}/bin/python -m pip install -r requirements.txt"
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

**What I tried:**

1 I tried this from the link below, the `connect econnrefused 9091` window doesn't display. But debugging is still not working.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53722540/665335

2 I tried all three approaches from this, none of it is working.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71852516/665335

**Environment**:

Azure Func core tool: 3.0.4626

Function Runtime Version: 3.9.0.0

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2135274
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools

VS Code: Version 1.69

Python: 3.9.13

Python extension: v2022.10.1

Azure Functions extension: v1.7.4

Comment: Can you please try changing the port number while executing i.e., func host start -port 9092

Comment: as mentioned on my OP, I tried that, not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I updated relevant extensions, it works now.

Examples of the extensions (not all) might be relevant:

Azure Function: 1.7.4

Jupyter: 2022.6.12

Pylance: 2022.7.40

Python: 2022.10.1

There might be more extensions for you to update. Try to resolve all relevant extension updates if possible.

[image]