# VSCode python debugger fails to attach to local port with ECONNREFUSED

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

I'm trying to debug locally a project that is deployed on Microsoft Azure.

I have a copy of the repository on my PC and setup the *launch.json* file as:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [


        {
            "name": "Attach to Python Functions",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9091,
            "preLaunchTask": "func: host start",
            "justMyCode": false,
        }
    ]
}
```

This has been working for days, but today is suddenly giving me problems. When in VSCode I click "Start debugging" I can see VSCode opening a new terminal, installing the dependencies specified in the virtual environment and executing `func: host start` as requested.

However, without a clear reason, today VSCode started showing an error message saying

```
connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9091
```

How can I fix this?

PS: I'm not an expert of VSCode, so please let me know if I omitted any useful information and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been receiving the same error quite a few times while I'm trying to run the azure function from Run -> Run without Debugging One of the workarounds that worked for me is to use the command `func host start` from the terminal.

[image]

Alternatively, you can update the .vscode/tasks.json file. For more information on this, you can check [VSCode is not starting Func Host Start properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677160/debug-on-python-azure-function-httptrigger-in-vscode-is-not-starting-func-host)

Comment: Once again: Please stop posting comments after answering, asking if you've solved someone's problem. Also: Please be sure to post properly formatted text, not images of text. See [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) for reasons why this is important.